# Angular Routing On Application Initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I Have a problem with Routing.

In my application, on startUp User must login so when connect to URL : http://localhost:4200, user start on a web page which is used to logged in, then if successfully logged go to URL http://localhost:4200/Home.

Some User start website directly from URL http://localhost:4200/Home, they must login then they are redirected to URL http://localhost:4200/Home/Home.

So I have a lot of default concerning Pictures, ...

How could I do in APP_INITIALIZER to force URL to be http://localhost:4200 when the user set browser like that : http://localhost:4200/Home ???

And second question, I wish to give access to user directly to certain page in clicking on a URL (received by mail) like that http://localhost:4200/Product/BeautifulCar1. User must absolutly be loggedIn to access thi URL.

So when clicking link, user goes to login Page then if successful user is automatically redirected to the product Page : http://localhost:4200/Product/BeautifulCar1
How can I do this ?

I Try injector in APP_INITIALIZER to have the currentRoute then put it in a variable redirect to route «  », and after logged in redirect to Product/BeautifulCar1 but without success.

I don’t understantd how to do it…

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a guard using [`CanActivate`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface:

> Interface that a class can implement to be a guard deciding if a route can be activated. If all guards return true, navigation continues. If any guard returns false, navigation is cancelled. If any guard returns a UrlTree, the current navigation is cancelled and a new navigation begins to the UrlTree returned from the guard.

You can find a full working example in the Tour of Heroes, the tutorial of angular [here](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh).

Basically a guard will check the current status of application (for example checking if you are authenticated or not) to choose if you can see a view or not.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already try this but Guard seems not to be call on app_iniitalizer...

I setup my route put the guard which check loggedIn or not but in debug mode on application startUp it didn't stop in when app initialized